# Visual Studio 2022 not running XUnit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, xunit

I've created a EntityFramework ASP.NET solution and i'm trying to create a XUnit test project to test my differents classes i've created.

I've created a TestClass for my Activity Class :

```
using LADS_Model;
using LADS_WebUI.Controllers;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;
using Assert = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert;

namespace LADS_XUnit
{
    public class UnitTest_Activity
    {
        [TestClass]
        public class ActivityController
        {
            private List<Activity> GetTestActivities()
            {
                var testActivities = new List<Activity>();
                testActivities.Add(new Activity { Id = 1, Name = "Chaussure" });
                testActivities.Add(new Activity { Id = 2, Name = "Crevettes" });
                testActivities.Add(new Activity { Id = 3, Name = "Sandwich" });
                return testActivities;
            }

            [TestMethod]
            public void GetAllActivities_ShouldReturnAllActivities()
            {
                var testActivities = GetTestActivities();
                var controller = new ActivityController();

                var result = controller.GetTestActivities();
                Assert.Equals(testActivities.Count, result.Count);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The problem is that when I launch my testClass, I do have the Test showing up in the test Explorer but VS tells me that the test did not execute and I have no idea why because it's not showing any errors or any messages to explain why it didnt execute

[image: capture of my test view]

Output of Tests :
[image: Output Tests]

Comment: Open the Output window (under the View menu), then select "Show output from: Tests". See what the error is.

Comment: @canton7 i've edited my message with the Output from Tests

Comment: Wait, you said xUnit right? `[TestMethod]` and `[TestClass]` aren't xUnit annotations. xUnit uses `[Fact]` on the test method, and nothing on the class

Comment: Do not nest classes

Comment: XUnit doesn't have anything like `[TestClass]`, any public class that has public void methods marked as `[Fact]` should be discovered and run. I'm not sure if it will handle nested classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem 1: xUnit vs. MSTest Attributes

- You're using the wrong method attributes for xUnit, so the xUnit Runner won't discover your tests:

  - You're using `[TestClass]` and `[TestMethod]`, but xUnit uses `[Fact]`/`[Theory]` only on methods, and doesn't use any attributes on test `class` types.
  - [xUnit's website has a table that matches and compares NUnit's, xUnit's, and MSTest's attributes](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons).
- So remove all `[TestClass]` attributes and change all `[TestMethod]` attributes to `[Fact]`.

---

I see you have this:

```cs
using Assert = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert;
```

...so I assume you're porting existing MSTest code to xUnit, in which case rather than changing the attributes in your code-base, you could alias MSTest's attributes to xUnit:

```cs
using TestClassAttribute  = SomeDummyAttribute;
using TestMethodAttribute = Xunit.FactAttribute;

internal sealed class SomeDummyAttribute : Attribute {}
```

If you're using C# 10.0 or later [you can use `global using` which will be shared by all source-files in the same project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

Also, consider using [Shouldly](https://github.com/shouldly/shouldly) or [Fluent Assertions](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions) instead of the `Assert`/`Asserts` classes.

### Problem 2: The `xunit.runner.visualstudio` NuGet package is dependent on your Visual Studio *and* .NET versions.

The `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package is rather finnicky about the specific versions of Visual Studio and .NET that you're using - unfortunately neither NuGet nor Visual Studio shows any message that updating `xunit.runner.visualstudio` to a version that drops support for your environment ([In my case, I was targeting .NET Core 3.1 but updated to `xunit.runner.visualstudio` 2.5.0](https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/issues/360) (which requires .NET 6.0+), and doing that made VS' Test Explorer just *fail silently* instead of listing the test-cases).

I've compiled the following table: make sure that your combination of Visual Studio *and* your target .NET platform/version is supported:

| xunit.runner.visualstudio | Release date | xUnit | Visual Studio | .NET Fx | .NET (.NET Core) | UWP | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.5.1 to 2.5.7 | 2023-07-06 | 1.9.2+ | VS2022 (v17.0+) | 4.6.2+ | 6.0+ |  |  |
| 2.5.0 | 2023-07-06 | 1.9.2+, 2.0+ | VS2019 (v16.10+) | 4.6.2+ | 6.0+ |  | Last version to *officially* support VS2019 ([theoretically, it should still work VS2019 but don't expect bugfixes](https://github.com/xunit/visualstudio.xunit/issues/400)). |
| 2.4.5 | 2022-05-05 | 1.9.2+, 2.0+ | VS2019 (v16.8+) | 4.7.2+ | 3.1+ | 10.0.16299+ | Last version to support .NET Core 3.1 and UWP. |
| 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 | 2020-06-02 | 1.9.2+, 2.0+ | VS2017 (v15.9+) | 2.0+ | 2.1+ | 10.0.16299+ | Last version to support Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Framework 2.0. |
| 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 | 2018-07-17 | 1.9.2+, 2.0+ | VS2012+ | 2.0+ | 1.0+ | 10.0+ | Last version to support Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013, and Visual Studio 2015. |
| 2.2.0 to 2.3.1 | 2017-02-20 | 1.9.2+, 2.0+ | VS2012+ | 2.0+ | 1.0+ | 10.0+ |  |
| 2.1.0 | 2015-09-27 | 1.9.2+, 2.0+ | VS2012+ | 2.0+ |  | 8.1, 10.0+ | Last version to support "Windows Store Apps" v8.1, Windows Phone 8.1, and Portable Class Library (Profile259). |

Answer (score 14):

I had a different issue with pretty much the exact same symptoms. **In my case I was simply missing the nuget package `xunit.runner.visualstudio`** which I had removed during some nuget troubleshooting.

It worked again immediately after installing it through the nuget GUI in Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you, first time trying unit tests with existing repo. But refactoring layers. The new layers are missing some packages. again, thank you! I was so confused.

Comment: Solved my problem. No idea, why I had to reinstall the runner ... yesterday everything was working perfectly, reboot -> runner missing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i was missing the nuget package `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`.
(you also need to install the nuget package `xunit.runner.visualstudio.`)

Answer (score 0):

These were what I needed

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.7.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform" Version="17.7.2" />
 <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.20.69" />
 <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.5.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="xunit.abstractions" Version="2.0.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.5.1">
```

Comment: For my `net8.0` framework project, I did not need `Microsoft.TestPlatform`, and I'm not currently using `Moq`, but the others were needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my whole solution was in .net core 5.0, so was the test project but xunit.runner.visualstudio works only from 6.0.
I changed only the test project to 6.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this combination of packages is not working with Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2022 17.9.0.  If I downgrade xunit.runner.visualstudio to version 2.5.6 or if I remove FluentAssertions, then Test Explorer will run the tests. This is with a .NET 8 project.

```
  <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.12.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.7.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.5.7"/>
```

Comment: The table in the accepted answer tells the same thing.